# unable to create keypair in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I added a user to a group in amazon AWS.  The user has the privilege of adding EC2 instances but does not appear to have the privilege of creating a keypair - the request is getting denied.  Any idea on what privilege needs to be added to enable this feature for the new user?

Comment: The most secure option is to have each user generate their own ssh keypair (ssh-keygen) and then import the public key into the AWS console.

Comment: yes, agreed.  I am curious why I do not have the privilege of creating a keypair using AWS - what privilege am I missing?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't have access to the AWS docs at the moment. My comment, though, is that your users should generate their own keys outside of AWS and then import the public key

Comment: @EEAA I think he's saying there's an IAM privilege required to do the actual import.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ahh, sure.

Comment: was missing administrator access - thanks everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specific IAM permission required is `ec2:ImportKeyPair`.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1472323724000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:ImportKeyPair"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: +1. **Much** better than the administrator option. :)

Answer (score -2):

I was missing the administrator policy for the user.  Once added in AWS, the new user could then import keypair or generate a new one.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: This gives them a *lot* of other privileges. See my answer if you want to limit to just that particular ability.

Comment: (I didn't downvote you, though)

Comment: its fine to downvote as long as someone actually gives a helpful answer - I do not care about the points here.  Thank you for the answer

Comment: The downvote was from me. While this answer theoretically *does* solve the problem, it solves it in perhaps the worst way possible: giving the user full administrative access to your AWS account. @ceejayoz's answer above is much better.